# HIVE: how to access elements in a MAP object

Tags: dictionary, object, hive

in my HIVE table *MYTABLE* I have one column "*MYCOL*" that contains this:

```
{"id": "a651b57f", 

 "items": {
    "ITEM1": {
        "code": "CODE1", 
        "name": "NAME1"}, 
    "ITEM2": {
        "code": "CODE2", 
        "name": "NAME2"}}, 

 "myinfo": {
    "c7daf1a9": {
        "id": "c7daf1a9", 
        "name": "newname", 
        "type": "newtype", 
        "appliedto": ["ITEM1", "ITEM2"]}}, 

 "info2": 12}
```

I would like to access the elements into "myinfo" and I tried something like this:

```
select  GET_JSON_OBJECT(t.MYCOL,'$.myinfo') FROM MYTABLE
```

but it doesn't work....

may someone help me?

thanks

Comment: actually I tried to replicate this into MYSQL and I have the same problem: I don't know how to access the "myinfo" elements....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the data in HDFS file have `one line` for **`each json row`** (not multiple new lines for one row).

- If json row is having multiple new lines then we need to replace all newlines for each row before storing into HDFS.

**Example:**

**`HDFS file data:`**

```
{"id": "a651b57f","items": {"ITEM1": {"code": "CODE1","name": "NAME1"},"ITEM2": {"code": "CODE2","name": "NAME2"}},"myinfo": {"c7daf1a9": {"id": "c7daf1a9","name": "newname","type": "newtype","appliedto": ["ITEM1", "ITEM2"]}},"info2": 12}
```

---

**`Hive:`**

```
with cte as (select string('{"id": "a651b57f","items": {"ITEM1": {"code": "CODE1","name": "NAME1"},"ITEM2": {"code": "CODE2","name": "NAME2"}},"myinfo": {"c7daf1a9": {"id": "c7daf1a9","name": "newname","type": "newtype","appliedto": ["ITEM1", "ITEM2"]}},"info2": 12}')my_col) --sample data
select get_json_object(my_col,'$.myinfo')jsn from cte;
```

**`Output:`**

```
{"c7daf1a9":{"id":"c7daf1a9","name":"newname","type":"newtype","appliedto":["ITEM1","ITEM2"]}}
```

---

**`Update`**

```
--to access name subfield we need to specify the path of json object
hive> select get_json_object(my_col,'$.myinfo.c7daf1a9.name')jsn from <table_name>;
--result
newname

hive> select get_json_object(my_col,'$.myinfo.c7daf1a9.appliedto')jsn from <table_name>;
--result
["ITEM1","ITEM2"]

hive> select get_json_object(my_col,'$.myinfo.c7daf1a9.appliedto[0]')jsn from <table_name>;
--result
ITEM1
```

Comment: Hi Shu and thanks

apologies for my doubt but: where have I to write the "with cte..." statement?
on HUE?

Comment: I already am able to access "myinfo" field... What I ask is to access the single subfields of "myinfo"

Comment: Hi Shu and thanks again. I don't know in advance the value of "myinfo" id, the one used to access the inner elements... how can I extract that id?

Comment: @mfran2002, In hive i don't think we can use achieve that case, as get_json_object not accepting wildcards!

Comment: wow...really? I have a problem then... Do you think I could use something as a workaround? python script maybe?